# maven warning: duplicate version when using two different types of dependecy of the same artifact

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Maven throws a strange warning while builduing our multi-module project. I'm just referencing the *jar* and *test-jar* of the same project in another project. Both dependencies have *test* scope. Im running Maven 3.3.1 and cannot upgrade the version easily.

Does anyone of you have an idea how I could solve the problem without getting this warning from maven?

**pom.xml of ProjectA:**

```
    <dependency> <!-- This is line 130 -->
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Warnings from maven (anonymized):**

> [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.group.ProjectA:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: ${project.groupId}:org.group.ProjectB:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${project.version} @ org.group.ProjectA, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/nicejob/workspace/org.group.ProjectA/pom.xml, line 130, column 15

Comment: The problem is that you have defined both in scope test which only makes sense for the `<type>test-jar</type>`.

Comment: Why doesn't it makes sense to add productive code of a module as a test-scoped dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [test-jar documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) I would say the two artifact are basically the same one, and that the "test-jar" one is not expected to be used aparte from test phase since it contains test classes.

A good approach could be:

- Leave the "standard" dependencies in compile scope (if you really need it for non-test classes it provides)
- Use the "test-jar" dependencies as an [additional dependency declaration](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag) (with test scope) of the surefire-plugin only, so that it's used only by the plugin itself